# Angular analysis in sDNA - sensitivity to small angular changes in road segments

Tags: angular, sdna

Space syntax analysis based on shortest angular path has a few issues due to the segregated design, with small changes in angles along a generally straight route adding to the summed angular changes along the route. This may or may not be desirable, and can be mitigated by setting angular thresholds.

How is this handled in sDNA? sDNA treats non-linear links as one unit, would that mean that for link-weighted analysis, angular changes are measured **between** two links, and not **along** two links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sDNA considers both changes within polylines and changes at junctions between polylines, but they are handled differently. With a hybrid metric you can set thresholds for angular change for junctions between polylines, e.g.

```
juncformula = rint(ang/45)*45
```

would round angular changes on junctions to the nearest 45 degrees, which approximates tulip analysis I think, if you exploded your network so there were no changes of direction within individual polylines (https://sdna.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna/wp-content/downloads/documentation/manual/sDNA_manual_v4_1_0/guide_to_individual_tools.html#expression-reference)

For angular changes within polylines this is not so straightforward unfortunately. The `lineformula` keyword tells sDNA how to process attributes of polylines, but *it does not process each change of direction within the polyline individually*. Instead they may be summed in arbitrary ways depending on the type of analyis (discrete or continuous, position of polyline centers, etc) before being passed to the `lineformula` expression. So if you wanted to round angular changes along the entire polyline to the nearest 45 degrees (which you may or may not want anyway) you would have to do something like

```
lineformula = (FULLang==0)? 0 : (rint(FULLang/45)*45 * ang/FULLang)
```

where the first part of that formula rounds the full angular cost of the polyline, and the second scales it to whatever part of the polyline sDNA is currently processing (based on distributing the rounded total angular change to the parts of the line where the unrounded angular change occurs).

Personally I don't round angular change like this, as I find it makes less difference in hybrid metrics that also include distance and other route characteristics anyway, but I can see how it makes sense for more spatial cognition focussed models.

Comment: Thank you, Sideshow Bob! Clear and consise.

Comment: No worries. I just realised my last formula fails on straight links so edited to account for that.